# create c# asynchronous socket client in multithreaded environment

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I am trying to create asynchronous socket client in multithreaded environment but it is not working correctly.
As below sample code,
If i create new AsyncSocketClient and call StartClent from multi-threaded environment it will process only one or two for rest, it is not processing.(I am creating new AsyncSocketClient with every new request)
Is it because of static variables,

```
 class AsyncSocketClient
    {

        private static AutoResetEvent sendDone =
            new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private static AutoResetEvent receiveDone =
            new AutoResetEvent(false);

        private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
new ManualResetEvent(false);

       static private String response = "";


        public void StartClent()
        {


            Socket workSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
           // clientSock.ReceiveTimeout = 1;


            try
            {
                workSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 8080), new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallBack), workSocket);
                connectDone.WaitOne();


                Send(s.workSocket, "<EOF>");
                sendDone.WaitOne();

                Receive(workSocket);
                receiveDone.WaitOne();


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        private void ConnectCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket workSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            workSocket.EndConnect(ar);
            connectDone.Set();
        }

        private void Receive(Socket client)
        {
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;
           client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), state);
        }

        private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            int byteReceived= client.EndReceive(ar);
            if (byteReceived > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length));
                Array.Clear(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length);
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), state);
            }
            else
            {
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }

        private void Send(Socket client,string data)
        {
            byte[] sendBufer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            client.BeginSend(sendBufer, 0, sendBufer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(BeginSendCallBack), client);

        }

        private void BeginSendCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
          int byteSent= client.EndSend(ar);
          Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", byteSent);
            sendDone.Set();
        }



    }

    public class StateObject
    {
        // Client socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public const int BufferSize = 30;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        // Received data string.
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    }
```

Comment: Your server isn't actually asynchronous, given that you're performing blocking waits all over the place on those static events.  Yes, they are very likely part of your problem.  In addition to being shared when it looks like they shouldn't be, you shouldn't be blocking in the first place.

Comment: @Servy This is as per the MSDN. Do we need to create a new socket for each and every request in multi threaded env.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user3597233 The example is correct in the need for a new socket for every request.  While the example is using the async calls since it blocks immediately it is essentially synchronous.  You should move your sending and receiving to the callback so StartClient does not block. You may want to draw out on paper what is happening and what you expect.  A UML sequence diagram might be helpful.

Comment: @DarrylBraaten I want to know if i create new AsyncSocketClient objects ,Are they execute uniquely or they will share some data

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a non blocking client and server with a simple echo implemented.  There is no error checking and nothing is closed correctly which should be done.  The server has some synchronous code just to make it easier to follow.

Client

```
public class AsyncClient
{
    private const int Port = 9999;
    private readonly string _clientId;
    private readonly Random _random;

    public AsyncClient(int clientId)
    {
        _clientId = string.Format("Client Id: {0}", clientId);
        _random =  new Random(clientId);
    }

    public void StartClient()
    {
        try
        {
            var workSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            var state = new ClientState { WorkSocket = workSocket };
            workSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, Port), ConnectCallBack, state);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ConnectCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var state = (ClientState) ar.AsyncState;
        state.WorkSocket.EndConnect(ar);
        Send(state);
    }

    private void Receive(ClientState clientState)
    {
        clientState.WorkSocket.BeginReceive(clientState.Buffer, 0, ClientState.BufferSize, 0, ReceiveCallBack, clientState);
    }

    private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var state = (ClientState) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.WorkSocket;
        int byteReceived= client.EndReceive(ar);
        if (byteReceived > 0)
        {
            var receivedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, byteReceived);
            Console.WriteLine("From Server: " + receivedString);
            Array.Clear(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length);
            state.Count++;
            Thread.Sleep(1000 + _random.Next(2000));
            Send(state);
        }
    }

    private void Send(ClientState clientState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending " + _clientId);
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("Send from Thread {0} Client id {1} Count {2}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, _clientId,clientState.Count));
        clientState.WorkSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0, BeginSendCallBack, clientState);
    }

    private void BeginSendCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var state = (ClientState) ar.AsyncState;
        int byteSent= state.WorkSocket.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", byteSent);
        Receive(state);
    }
}

public class ClientState
{
    // Client socket.
    public Socket WorkSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

    public int Count = 0;
}
```

Server

```
public class AsyncServer
{
    private const int Port = 9999;
    public void StartServer()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(Run) {IsBackground = true};
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running");
        var tcpListener =  new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, Port);
        tcpListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before Accept");
            var state = new ServerState {WorkSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket()};
            Console.WriteLine("Before Recieve");
            Receive(state);
        }
    }

    private void Receive(ServerState state)
    {
        state.WorkSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, ServerState.BufferSize, 0, ReceiveCallBack, state);
    }

    private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ReceiveCallBack");
        var state = (ServerState) ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            int byteReceived= state.WorkSocket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (byteReceived > 0)
            {
                var receivedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, byteReceived);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + receivedString);
                var bytesToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Server Got --> " + receivedString);
                Array.Copy(bytesToSend, state.Buffer, bytesToSend.Length);
                state.WorkSocket.Send(state.Buffer, 0, bytesToSend.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                Array.Clear(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length);
                Receive(state);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    private class ServerState
    {
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        public readonly byte[] Buffer = new byte[1024];
        public Socket WorkSocket;
    }
```

I have run this using a console you can either have two applications or just launch the client and server separately.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 0)
        {
            var server = new AsyncServer();
            server.StartServer();
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var client = new AsyncClient(i);
                client.StartClient();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```