# Program connects to server on localhost, but doesn't work over lan or internet

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I made super simple game on plain C# using Windows Forms to learn a little bit about making programs "talk" over internet. Server and client are on same program and user just chooses which one he is by clicking a button.

It currently works just as I want as long as server and client are both ran on same PC using ip 127.0.0.1 to connect. If I try to use internal or external ip (port is opened) it doesn't work anymore ("Before Accept" triggers, but "Before Receive" doesn't).

I got base for my code from Darryl Braaten who answered someone elses question:
[create c# asynchronous socket client in multithreaded environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614123/create-c-sharp-asynchronous-socket-client-in-multithreaded-environment)

AsyncServer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace blockbattle
{
    public class AsyncServer
    {
        private const int port = 11000;
        public int clientID = -1;
        public string serverPos = "";
        public string clientPos = "";
        public string newBullets = "";
        public bool bulletsSent = false;
        public string receivedBullets = "";

        public void StartServer()
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(Run) { IsBackground = true };
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Running");
            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
            tcpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Before Accept");
                ServerState state = new ServerState { WorkSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket() };
                Debug.WriteLine("Before Receive");
                Receive(state);
            }
        }

        private void Receive(ServerState state)
        {
            state.WorkSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, ServerState.BufferSize, 0, ReceiveCallBack, state);
        }

        private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            ServerState state = (ServerState)ar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                int byteReceived = state.WorkSocket.EndReceive(ar);
                if (byteReceived > 0)
                {
                    string receivedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, byteReceived);

                    string[] receivedData = receivedString.Split('+');

                    clientID = int.Parse(receivedData[0]);
                    clientPos = receivedData[1];
                    if (receivedData[2].Length > 0)
                        receivedBullets = receivedData[2];

                    byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}+{1}", serverPos, newBullets));
                    if (newBullets.Length > 0)
                    {
                        newBullets = "";
                        bulletsSent = true;
                    }

                    Array.Copy(bytesToSend, state.Buffer, bytesToSend.Length);
                    state.WorkSocket.Send(state.Buffer, 0, bytesToSend.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                    Array.Clear(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length);
                    Receive(state);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Print(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private class ServerState
        {
            public const int BufferSize = 1024;
            public readonly byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            public Socket WorkSocket = null;
        }
    }
}
```

AsyncClient.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace blockbattle
{
    public partial class AsyncClient
    {
        private const int port = 11000;
        private readonly int _clientId;
        private readonly Random _random;
        public string clientPos = "";
        public string serverPos = "";
        public string newBullets = "";
        public bool bulletsSent = false;
        public string receivedBullets = "";
        public string lastBullet = "";

        public AsyncClient(int clientId)
        {
            _clientId = clientId;
            _random = new Random(clientId);
        }

        public void StartClient(IPAddress serverIP)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket workSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                ClientState state = new ClientState { WorkSocket = workSocket };
                workSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(serverIP, port), ConnectCallBack, state);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void ConnectCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            ClientState state = (ClientState)ar.AsyncState;
            state.WorkSocket.EndConnect(ar);
            Send(state);
        }

        private void Receive(ClientState clientState)
        {
            clientState.WorkSocket.BeginReceive(clientState.Buffer, 0, ClientState.BufferSize, 0, ReceiveCallBack, clientState);
        }

        private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            ClientState state = (ClientState)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.WorkSocket;
            int byteReceived = client.EndReceive(ar);
            if (byteReceived > 0)
            {
                string receivedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, byteReceived);
                string[] receivedData = receivedString.Split('+');

                serverPos = receivedData[0];
                if (receivedData[1].Length > 0)
                    receivedBullets = receivedData[1];

                Array.Clear(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length);
                Thread.Sleep(33);
                Send(state);
            }
        }

        private void Send(ClientState clientState)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}+{1}+{2}", _clientId, clientPos, newBullets));
            if (newBullets.Length > 0)
            {
                newBullets = "";
                bulletsSent = true;
            }

            try
            {
                clientState.WorkSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0, BeginSendCallBack, clientState);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void BeginSendCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            ClientState state = (ClientState)ar.AsyncState;
            int byteSent = state.WorkSocket.EndSend(ar);
            Receive(state);
        }
    }

    public class ClientState
    {
        // Client socket.
        public Socket WorkSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

        public int Count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your firewall and port forwarding settings.

Comment: @SLaks I have disabled firewall and opened the port. Also built this example from Microsoft and it works just fine: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `IPAddress.Loopback` to `IPAddress.Any` in your `TcpListener`.

Comment: Oh damn so simple mistake and I have been banging my head to the wall. Thank you so much!